# React Native Picker - On press event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fairly new to programming in react native and having an issue with the android keyboard not closing on pressing of a Picker. I did a little bit of research on if `<Picker>` has an onPress prop and it dosent seem like it does. Does anyone know a work around?

Below is a screenshot of the issue I am having and a code snippet of how I am constructing my input and picker!

Note: I am using Native Base :)

[See screenshot here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2DjR.png)

```
<Label>Species Code</Label>
<Item regular>
    <Input keyboardType={"number-pad"} ref="speciesCode" returnKeyType={"next"} onSubmitEditing={() => { this.refs["dbh"]._root.focus() }} blurOnSubmit={true} value={this.state && this.state.selectedSpeciesCode ? this.state.selectedSpeciesCode : ""} onChangeText={(text) => this.handleSpeciesCodeChange(text)} />
</Item>
<Label>Species</Label>
<View>
    <Picker
        mode="dropdown"
        iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
        style={{ width: undefined, borderWidth: 1 }}
        placeholder="Please select Species"
        placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
        placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedSpeciesId}
        onValueChange={this.handleSpeciesChange.bind(this)}

    >
        <Picker.Item label={"Please Select"} value={null} />
        {speciesList}
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use refs? You can assign the Picker a ref, and then when it becomes the 'focussed' element you can call `Keyboard.dismiss()`. Docs on refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html